# How to call an activity method from a fragment?

Tags: java, android

I need to call a method that is in an activity from a fragment , i can't even instatiate the activity in the fragment , I don't know how to approach this problem. I need to call the activity's method from an onClick that is part of the fragment , because i need to update a value because it changed (ex: the value is 1 , after onClick the value is 2 but the activity doesn't update).

This is the method from the activity :

```
   public void onUpdate(){

    //setCount.setText(Integer.toString(new Database(this).getCountCart(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())));
    setCount.setText(Integer.toString(new Database(this).getTotalCount(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())));

    cart = new Database(this).getCarts(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    int total = 0;
    for(OrderModel order:cart)
        total+=(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(order.getPret()))) *(order.getCantitate());
    Locale locale = new Locale("ro","RO");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    totalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));

}
```

Here is where i try to call it from the fragment:

```
fragmentItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
  new Database(getActivity().getBaseContext()).increaseCart(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),fragmentUnuModel.getDenumire());
  food.onUpdate();
}
```

And here is the error :

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.cosnila.orderme.Food.onUpdate()' on a null object reference
    at com.cosnila.orderme.Fragments.FragmentUnu$1$1.onClick(FragmentUnu.java:123)
```

Comment: There is nothing special about this method that needs to be in the activity. You can make it a static method in a Utils class.

Comment: @Josh i have 2 TextViews that need to be set, how do i do exactly ?

Comment: in `new Databse( (getContext()) ...)` try that parameter instead. Did you setup your rootview?

Comment: so is this the host activity for your fragment?

Comment: @Josh the fragment is in the activity , but i have a ViewPagerAdapter that creates my fragments.

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ already tried that , same error , null object referece

Comment: i think you need to review fragment lifecycle a bit more [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) . when creating a fragment in the `onCreateView` you should create a reference to mRootView, so something like this `mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout_file, container, false)` and mRootView is `private var mRootView: View` or in Kotlin `private lateinit var mRootView: View`, this way inside that static function you can go mRootView.getContext() (you won't need this because you can't use this in static scope)

Comment: I think this should be a straightforward interface (listener) in the fragment and implemented by Activity.

Comment: @Josh i thought about that also , but i would be easier if i just call the method , the thing is i don't understand why if i try to instantiate the activity is always null

Comment: to launch an activity, you need intents and fragment isn't a place to do that. Even if you are able to instantiate a new object, it won't affect anything as it's a new plain object that's good for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have method **onUpdate** in your activity and want to call an activity method from fragment, call it as below in fragment where required.

((YouActivityName) getActivity()).onUpdate();

Be sure to replace your activity name.

Answer (score 0):

```
img_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent displayFlights = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectFlight.class);
            startActivity(displayFlights);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make onUpdate() `static`.

Your method header should look like this:

```
public static void onUpdate() {
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin instead of java you should try this

```
(activity as yourActivityName?)?.yourPublicMethod()
```